# Can anyone help me out from the error list in the pic?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

[image]
i have an error of "unforunatly sotp" i want to open splesh first then MainActivity and then from main Activity there is a menu which give me option to open check class... i am getting error pzz help me 
Code of AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fypproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
   <application android:icon="@drawable/fypicon" 
     android:label="@string/app_name">
   <activity
        android:name=".Splesh"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.fypproject.Check"
        android:label="@string/app_name">            
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.fypproject.CHECK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fypproject.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">           
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
</application>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
 </manifest>
```

here is my MainActivity

```
  package com.example.fypproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;    
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
   import android.app.PendingIntent; 
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent; 
  import android.content.IntentFilter;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1,b2;
    b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bmenu);
    b1.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }
    @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu1, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu1, v, menuInfo);
    CreateMenu(menu1);
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MenuChoice(item);
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0,0,0,"Check Status");
        {
            mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0,1,1,"Contact Us");
        {
            mnu2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0,2,2,"About Us");
        {
            mnu3.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
     }
     private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "This is item1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Check.class));
            return true;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,ContactUs.class));
            return true;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,AboutUs.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
    }
```

here is my MainActivity XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Fyp Project"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/bmenu"
    android:layout_width="475sp"
    android:layout_height="70sp"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
   ></Button>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is not a lot to go on in your question. Do you have code that you can post to clarify what you're asking? Is there an error log? Anything?

Comment: @Aziz rahman show us what you have tried. No one in the community is Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: from the image you posted above, the log stated that there is no such activity that handles the intent you passed to it, have you declared your activity inside the manifest ?

Comment: CodeMonkey Sir i have posted the code can you help me....plz

Answer (score 0):

The action that you have mentioned is xx.xxx.aziz.Mainactivity. But according to your Manifest the MainActivity seems to have an intent filter action
android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY
So either modify the calling action or modify your manifest to match the calling action